# Dark winter days equal dark winter drinks!

Tags: wine, recommendations, gin

Winter is just around the corner, thus what should I be drinking?  My normal summer tipple of Gin and Tonic, or should I move over to darker more homely drinks, like perhaps rum and coke?  Is there a particular wine that is evocative of cold days and warm fireplaces?  Or perhaps I should just simply remove ice from gin and carry on - any suggestions?

Comment: This question in it's current format isn't really a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. Broad suggestions are primarily opinion based, but the question could be re-worded to look for drinks that are most commonly drunk in the winter

Comment: Have you done a Google search. Lots of stuff comes up for “winter cocktail” like https://www.esquire.com/food-drink/drinks/gmp385/winter-cocktails/

Comment: I get where you are coming from, however simply googling it would mean that no one ever came to this site.  I will however try to re-word it.

Comment: Personal, winter is stout season.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just go ahead and answer this question assuming it's better formed, something like:

- **Which drinks are most popular in the winter?**

The difference to me in which drinks to choose in the summer versus the winter comes from the *temperature in which you're drinking*. In the summer people typically crave something that is light, cool, and refreshing in the hot weather, where in the winter they want something that sticks to their bones and warms the cockles. Some examples:

**Summer Drinks**

- Pilsner
- Lager
- Weiss
- IPAs
- Fruity cocktails (vodka, rum)
- Caesars
- Light bodied, medium to sweet wines

**Winter Drinks**

- Stouts
- Porters
- Full bodied, dry red wines
- Mulled Wine
- Whisky
- Brandy
- Autumn or Winter (spiced) ales

**Caveat**

That said, really just drink and enjoy whatever you want, whenever you want. But in my experience it's usually the summer when I don't want the heavier drinks rather than vice versa. I'm much more likely to drink a light beer in the winter than something dark in the summer, although I'll drink whisky all year round.

Comment: I love the Caveat!

Comment: In particular I think of rose as a summer wine. Hot coffee based cocktails like Irish coffee are winter drinks.

Comment: What is it that distinguishes between these two groups?  Is it calories, alcohol strength, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

**Dark winter days equal dark winter drinks!**

Darker winter days equals dark wines: **black wines**.

I would recommend a very dark red wine, if it is dark enough it almost almost black!

> Wait, what the heck is black wine? Despite its nickname, it’s a red wine made from Saperavi grapes—but its color is such a rich, dark purple, that it looks black. Saperavi is Georgia’s most popular red wine, and the grapes are now being grown throughout the world, including the Finger Lakes region of the U.S., Australia and Eastern Europe. - [Psst: **Black Wine** Is the New Trend You Need to Know](https://www.purewow.com/wine/georgian-black-wine-saperavi-grapes)

[image: Saperavi]

> [**Saperavi**](http://www.lukasiwinery.com/saperavi2/)
>
> Dry red wine
>
> Coupled with the aroma acquired after aging in oak barrels, it also brings the flavors of ripe blueberry, caramel and blackcurrant.
>
> This wine, which is intended for a long-term aging, offers a velvet finish and touchy feeling of tannin at the same time.
>
> The balance of aroma, structure and texture places Lukasi’s Saperavi among the best wines.
>
> It is recommended to pair it with meat dishes, game, salads, and the best hard cheese.
> Best to drink at  +18 C° –  +20 C°.
>
> Alcohol – 11.5% – 13%
>
> It is complementary to robust meat flavours, hunted meat, salads, and aged cheese.